# Automatically keyed map

Tags: java, collections

I have written a class that is designed to be an automatically keyed `Map` in Java.

Here is my implementation:

```java
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * A {@link Map} that is automatically keyed.
 *
 * @param <K> the key type for the map
 * @param <V> the value type for the map
 * @param <M> the type of map to use internally
 */
public abstract class AutoKeyedMap<K, V, M extends Map<K, V>> implements Map<K, V> {
    private final M map;
    private boolean preventOverwrite;

    /**
     * Constructs a new automatically keyed map that wraps the provided map.
     *
     * @param map              the map to wrap
     * @param preventOverwrite prevent overwriting of existing keys
     */
    public AutoKeyedMap(final M map, final boolean preventOverwrite) {
        this.map = map;
        this.preventOverwrite = preventOverwrite;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new automatically keyed map that wraps the provided map.
     *
     * @param map the map to wrap
     */
    public AutoKeyedMap(final M map) {
        this(map, false);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the key for the provided value.
     *
     * <p>
     * This method looks up or calculates a key for the provided value.
     *
     * It has no implementation by default and therefore it's workings are implementation dependant.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param value the value to get the key for
     *
     * @return the key for the provided value
     */
    public abstract K getKey(final V value);

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the map prevents overwriting of keys.
     *
     * @return whether or not the map prevents overwriting of keys
     */
    public final boolean doesPreventOverwrite() {
        return preventOverwrite;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the map being wrapped by the wrapped map.
     *
     * @return the map being wrapped by the wrapped map
     */
    public final M getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    /**
     * Clears the map.
     *
     * @see Map#clear()
     */
    public final void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the wrapped map contains the provided key.
     *
     * @param key the key to check
     *
     * @return whether or not the wrapped map contains the provided key
     *
     * @see Map#containsKey(Object)
     */
    public final boolean containsKey(final Object key) {
        return map.containsKey(key);
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the wrapped map contains the provided value.
     *
     * @param value the value to check
     *
     * @return whether or not the wrapped map contains the provided value
     *
     * @see Map#containsValue(Object)
     */
    public final boolean containsValue(final Object value) {
        return map.containsValue(value);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the entry set for the wrapped map.
     *
     * @return the entry set for the wrapped map
     *
     * @see Map#entrySet()
     */
    public final Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return map.entrySet();
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the wrapped map is equal to the provided object.
     *
     * @param o the object to check
     *
     * @return whether or not the wrapped map is equal to the provided object
     *
     * @see Map#equals(Object)
     */
    public final boolean equals(final Object o) {
        return map.equals(o);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value for the provided key.
     *
     * @param key the key to get the value for
     *
     * @return the value for the provided key
     *
     * @see Map#get(Object)
     */
    public final V get(final Object key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the hash code of the wrapped map.
     *
     * @return the hash code of the wrapped map
     *
     * @see Map#hashCode()
     */
    public final int hashCode() {
        return map.hashCode();
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the wrapped map is empty.
     *
     * @return whether or not the wrapped map is empty.
     *
     * @see Map#isEmpty()
     */
    public final boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the key set of the wrapped map.
     *
     * @return the key set of the wrapped map
     *
     * @see Map#keySet()
     */
    public final Set<K> keySet() {
        return map.keySet();
    }

    /**
     * Puts a key/value pair in the wrapped map.
     *
     * <p>
     * If the key is not <code>null</code> then this method will throw an {@link UnsupportedOperationException}.
     *
     * This is due to the fact that the key is automatically derived by {@link #getKey(Object)} and should not be
     * provided manually.
     * </p>
     *
     * <p>
     * If the key derived by {@link #getKey(Object)} already exists in the map and <code>preventOverwrite</code> is
     * <code>true</code> (i.e. {@link #doesPreventOverwrite()} returns <code>true</code>) then this method will throw
     * an {@link IllegalStateException}.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param key the key for the key/value pair
     * @param value the value for the key/value pair
     *
     * @return the previous value associated with the provided key
     *
     * @see Map#put(Object, Object)
     */
    public final V put(final K key, final V value) {
        if (key != null) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("cannot put value with non-null key");
        }

        final K generatedKey = getKey(value);

        if (map.containsKey(generatedKey)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("derived key already exists");
        }

        return map.put(generatedKey, value);
    }

    /**
     * Puts all of the key/values pairs from the provided map into the wrapped map.
     *
     * @param m the map to retrieve the key/value pairs from
     *
     * @see #put(Object, Object)
     * @see Map#putAll(Map)
     */
    public final void putAll(final Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for (final Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : m.entrySet()) {
            put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the value with the provided key.
     *
     * @param key the key of the value to remove
     *
     * @return the previous value for the provided key
     *
     * @see Map#remove(Object)
     */
    public final V remove(final Object key) {
        return map.remove(key);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the size of the wrapped map.
     *
     * @return the size of the wrapped map
     *
     * @see Map#size()
     */
    public final int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the values of the wrapped map.
     *
     * @return the values of the wrapped map
     *
     * @see Map#values()
     */
    public final Collection<V> values() {
        return map.values();
    }
}
```

And a (basic) example of how I'd use it:

```
public class ClassMap<V, M> extends AutoKeyedMap<Class<?>, V, M> {
    public ClassMap(M map, boolean preventOverwrite) {
        super(map, preventOverwrite);
    }

    public ClassMap(M map) {
        super(map);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getKey(V value) {
        return value.getClass();
    }
}
```

This would allow me to create a map of objects and their classes, and if I set `preventOverwrite` to true it would allow me to have a non-overwritable map of objects and their classes. The primary use of this is in an Entity Component System, where I can keep a map of classes and their corresponding components (as you can only have a single component of each type).

I have one main "gripes" with my current code, albeit not that large, but I'd like to see what others think.

I think that the documentation could be better - in it's current state most of the documentation is rather pointless, as it doesn't really tell you much about most of the methods. I'm not sure if this is a good thing or not, as we are pretty much re-implementing `Map` for the most part (excluding one or two methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [h.j.k.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/24141/h-j-k)'s [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/127348/95296), I would definitely remove the method:

```
public final M getMap() {
    return map;
}
```

You don't need this and this is smelly: all of the other methods delegate rightfully to that map so having this getter is actually the source of bugs and confusion. If you have an instance of a concrete class, then you will be allowed to call `getMap()` and `put` what you want inside it, thereby completely disregarding your allow overwrite policy.

As an example, consider

```
class BuggedImpl extends AutoKeyedMap<String, String, Map<String, String>> {
    public BuggedImpl() {
        super(new HashMap<>(), true); // <-- true to prevent overwrite
    }
    @Override
    public String getKey(String value) {
        return value; // <-- just returning the value (pure example)
    }
}
```

Then, you can have:

```
BuggedImpl impl = new BuggedImpl();
impl.put(null, "A");
impl.put(null, "A"); // <-- this will correctly throw an IllegalStateException
```

but

```
BuggedImpl impl = new BuggedImpl();
impl.put(null, "A");
System.out.println(impl.get("A")); // <-- prints the correct A
impl.getMap().put("A", "H");
System.out.println(impl.get("A")); // <-- prints H, ops, the map was overwritten when it shouldn't have been
```

The presence of the getter allowed the client to modify the internal map, when this shouldn't have been possible.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bug

You have a `preventOverwrite` flag, but you don't actually use it in your `Map.put(K, V)` method:

```
public final V put(final K key, final V value) {
    if (key != null) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("cannot put value with non-null key");
    }
    final K generatedKey = getKey(value);
    // @Tunaki's comment
    if (preventOverwrite && map.containsKey(generatedKey)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("derived key already exists");
    }
    return map.put(generatedKey, value);
}
```

#### `boolean` methods

`doesPreventOverwrite()` is an unconventional `boolean` method name, for consistency you may want to call it as `isOverwritable()`, with the inverse meaning of course (i.e. `doesPreventOverwrite() == !isOverwritable()`).

#### Maps of objects and their classes

Conveniently, if this is your only use case so far, you can also consider using Guava's [`ClassToInstanceMap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#classtoinstancemap) to have the same functionality.

Comment: I would do the check as `preventOverwrite && map.containsKey(generatedKey)` instead (wich will short-circuit if the flag is false).

Comment: @Tunaki edited to reflect your suggestion. :)